# how to divide each row by the sum of those rows?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table `CREDITS` with these columns:

- DAY_OPERATIONAL
- TOTAL_LOAN
- CREDITS_PERCENT

I should multiply each row's `TOTAL_LOAN` and `CREDITS_PERCENT` then divide to `SUM(TOTAL_LOAN)` in that `DAY_OPERATIONAL`.

My code is not working.

How can I achieve this? How do I need to use group by properly?

```
SELECT 
    (total_loan * credits_percent) / SUM(total_loan) 
FROM
    credits
WHERE
    day_operational = '29.12.2021'
```

Comment: Can you share sample data set and desired results please?

Answer (score 1):

This is how I understood the question.

`tc` and `tl` are here just to show what values were used to compute the final `result`.

```
SQL> with credits (day_operational, total_loan, credits_percent) as
  2    (select date '2021-12-01', 100, 1 from dual union all
  3     select date '2021-12-01', 200, 4 from dual union all
  4     --
  5     select date '2021-12-02', 500, 5 from dual
  6    )
  7  select day_operational,
  8         sum(total_loan * credits_percent) tc,
  9         sum(total_loan) tl,
 10         --
 11         sum(total_loan * credits_percent) / sum(total_loan) result
 12  from credits
 13  group by day_operational
 14  order by day_operational;

DAY_OPERAT         TC         TL     RESULT
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
01.12.2021        900        300          3
02.12.2021       2500        500          5

SQL>
```

So:

```
01.12.2021: 100 * 1 + 200 * 4 = 100 + 800 =  900
            100 + 200                     =  300  -->  900 / 300 = 3

02.12.2021: 500 * 5                       = 2500
            500                           =  500  --> 2500 / 500 = 5
```

---

As of `day_operational`: if its datatype is `date` (should be!), then don't compare it to strings. `'29.12.2021'` is a string. Use

- date literal (as I did): `date '2021-12-29'` or
- `to_date` function with appropriate format mask:

  ```
  to_date('29.12.2021', 'dd.mm.yyyy')
  ```

Answer (score 0):

`TOTAL_LOAN * CREDITS_PERCENT / SUM(TOTAL_LOAN)`

`=`

`CREDITS_PERCENT * (TOTAL_LOAN / SUM(TOTAL_LOAN)`

hence

```
SELECT
  day_operational
, credits_percent * RATIO_TO_REPORT(total_loan) OVER (PARTITION BY day_operational)
FROM credits
```

See [RATIO_TO_REPORT](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/RATIO_TO_REPORT.html)